# working with integer ranges in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, range

I have a `tibble` that encodes when each of 300 counties experienced a (potentially) recurrent event.  The "shape of the data" is:

```
county  event_start  event_end
A       3            6
A       12           20
A       71           80
B       1            3
B       19           30
...
```

Some helpful characteristics here:

- There is no missing data.
- No county has two events that overlap (event_start_2 is always greater than event_end_1 for two events)
- Within county, the events are sorted.

I want to reshape the data to be more like this:

```
county   day    event
A        1      no
A        2      no
A        3      yes
A        4      yes
A        5      yes
A        6      yes
A        7      no
...
```

I can imagine how to do this with a bunch of `for` loops and such.  But is there a `dplyr`ish way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to get the sequence between corresponding elements of 'event_start', 'event_end' with `map`, `unnest` the `list` output to expand the data, use `complete` to fill up the 'day' and `replace` the `NA` elements with 'no' for the 'event' column

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   transmute(county, day = map2(event_start, event_end, seq), event = 'yes') %>% 
   unnest %>% 
   group_by(county) %>% 
   complete(day = seq_len(max(day))) %>%
   mutate(event = replace(event, is.na(event), 'no'))
# A tibble: 110 x 3
# Groups:   county [2]
#   county   day event
#   <chr>  <int> <chr>
# 1 A          1 no   
# 2 A          2 no   
# 3 A          3 yes  
# 4 A          4 yes  
# 5 A          5 yes  
# 6 A          6 yes  
# 7 A          7 no   
# 8 A          8 no   
# 9 A          9 no   
#10 A         10 no   
# ... with 100 more rows
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(county = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), event_start = c(3L, 
12L, 71L, 1L, 19L), event_end = c(6L, 20L, 80L, 3L, 30L)), .Names = c("county", 
"event_start", "event_end"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I am gobsmacked at how quickly this got answered and how perfect the answer is.